# Next js delay before applying Emotion and MUI styles

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, material-ui, emotion

I'm using `emotion/react: ^11.10.5`, `mui/material: ^5.11.0` and `Next.js v13.1.2`;
And I've used MUI `sx` and Emotion/React `css` to style my react components,
also most of the pages are SSR.

Problem is that styles are applied with delay, so the page is rendered, or loaded without any style, and after a second styles are applied.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem?